# Wikitude SDK - range

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am using the Wikitude API to develop an AR application for android. 
I would to define the range to search for the poi's, but i can't find it anywhere. 
Does the api permit to define the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the ActionRanges in the Wikitude reference library. That is what you are looking for in terms of radius and geofence.

http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/Reference/JavaScript%20Reference/ActionRange.html

```
actionRange = new AR.ActionRange(geoObject, 500);
```

From the documentation

```
AR.ActionRange ( geoLocation , radius , options )
Parameters:
geoLocation <GeoLocation> a single GeoLocation defining the center point of the circle.
radius <float> the radius of the ActionRange in meters.
options <object> Setup-Parameters to customize additional object properties.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mentioned Android API is deprecated and offers a very limited feature-set.

Please have a look at
http://www.wikitude.com/developer/architect

Here you find latest Version of the SDK which enables offline usage, and a huge number of customizations (animations, html, CSS, JS...)
It is JS based and allows you to build mobile AR apps without any sensor-handling.

Kind regards,
Andi (from Wikitude's Android Team)

Comment: I have downloaded the last version of the Wikitude. Maybe i explained it wrong. The range that is was referring i think it is the Geo Trigger (geofence). How can we define the range?